# AWS EFS Backup using Datapipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-efs

I want to take backup of my EFS production environment.
I have setup solution as defined in walk through
with 2 EFS Production & EFS Backup

I created 4 security groups : 
1) efs-mt-sg (EFS SG) & add access to efs-ec2-sg on NFS port.
2) efs-ec2-sg(EC2 SG).
3) efs-backup-mt-sg (backup EFS SG) & add access to efs-ec2-backup-sg on NFS port.
4) efs-ec2-backup-sg(backup EC2 SG).

I have setup data pipline using template  https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/blob/master/samples/EFSBackup/1-Node-EFSBackupPipeline.json

Now when I activate this pipeline it runs well with status Finished and shows me logs as in Stdout with all command executed, but i don't see any backup in my backup EFS when i mount in ec2 and check size of same comparing with production EFS.
Where as, when I add an EC2 instance using security groups efs-ec2-sg,efs-ec2-backup-sg and run all specified commands in https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/blob/master/samples/EFSBackup/efs-backup.sh it works well and i can see this EFS file system with backup files.

How can i get this data pipeline work through?

Comment: When I run command manually on EC2 Instance it takes time to execute as there is 15GB of data where as data pipeline runs this in few seconds but with no data for backup, not sure what is wrong. Any help!